# Magento2 Disable All Modules of a Particular Vendor Name

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1

I would like disable all module of a particular vendor in a single command.

I know we have `php bin/magento module:disable [Vendor_ModuleName]` command but as far as I know it doesnot take wild cards like `php bin/magento module:disable Foo_*`.

I was wondering if they is way to do this in a single go ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok so tried out some commands and seems like linux shell piping commands can help with this:

**Disable all modules for a particular vendor name**:

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep [VendorName] | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$' | xargs php bin/magento module:disable -f
```

Example:

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep Foo_ | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable -f
```

**Disable all custom modules except Magento's core modules**:

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable -f
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Some support for wildcards would be nice though (and logic)

Comment: Don't know why, but when I tried the first command to disable all modules for a particular vendor, it disabled ALL modules and not sure how to restore Magento modules as it throws an error now even with module:status command... M2.3.3