# How to disable all extensions by a vendor

Tags: magento-2.1

I am stuck with a crappy vendor whose extensions have lot of bugs.

I want to disable all the extensions from that vendor for sometime, without deleting the inside settings, to check if some other problems are caused by this extension or not.

How can I disable all extension from a vendor in shortest possible way?

Comment: Related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160352/magento2-disable-all-modules-of-a-particular-vendor-name

Answer (score 20):

You can try something like this, this is one-liner command. And it will find & disable all modules except which one start with `Magento_`

```
$ php bin/magento module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

To disable all module for particular vendor, you could use something like this

```
$ php bin/magento module:status | grep VendorName_ | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

The differences is one with `grep -v Magento` and the other is `grep VendorName_` :)

Comment: yes, I was looking for something like this. will check soon and let you know.

Comment: Yes, it does what you say.
But I want to disable extensions that starts with `vendorname_`.
Not except `vendorname_`

Comment: @kashish Change Magento in previous command to VendorName. That's just an example, you can do anything you want :)

Comment: you didn't understand my previous comment. I mean I want to disable all the extensions that starts with `vendorname_`, not disable  all the extensions that starts except `vendorname_`

Comment: @kashish Please check my updated answer :)

Comment: I checked! Didn't work for me.
No matter whatever vendorname I write, It disables magento extensions.

Comment: @kashish: Works for me http://imgur.com/a/xSeBk

Answer (score 1):

Try this from command bash:

Go to your Magento root directory and run this command:

`php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module1 Vendor_Module2 ..`

Add this at the end of command to clear modules static contents:

`--clear-static-content`

**Note:** you can see the list of all modules by:

`php bin/magento module:status`

Comment: I know this will work, but there are about 30 extensions. Typing all of them will take lot of time. I think there must be a shorter way.

Comment: btw, when I enable the extensions later, will the settings of extensions be still there or will it be removed?

Comment: Extension's setting is saved in Database so it will not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily disable all your extension from `app>etc>config.php`

In this file you can find

```
<?php
return array (
  'modules' => 
  array (
    'NAMESPACE_MODULENAME' => 1,
    'Magento_Store' => 1    
...............................    
  ),
);
```

Where `1` is enable and `0` means disable the extension. So just find the your custom modules from this file and set it `0`. and run rest of the magento commands like, `di:compile`, `cache:flush`, `static-content:deploy`.

---

***Note: this is for debugging purpose, we should always use `command line***