# Magento 2: Disable all custom and Third Party Module in single Command

Tags: magento2, module, cli

Is there is any way that we can disable all custom and third party Module in a single command? Currently, I am using below command to disable multiple modules

> php bin/magento module:disable module1 module2 module3....moduleN

Currently I am defining all module but I don't want to define all modules since there are so many modules.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

Credit : [Toan Nguyen](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/18821/toan-nguyen)

[Source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191344/2589)

Comment: Will this disable all custom and third party modules,means which are exist in app/code folder?

Comment: Yes, but without Magento

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide link to the original thread instead of the user.

Comment: Yes, just updated the answer, thanks :) @RajeevKTomy

Comment: Does not work all the time, sometimes it throws errors that it cant disable a module because some other module depends on it.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply disable what modules you want by modify in app/etc/config.php file the value form 1 to 0 for the specific module. and the run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

Example:

```
'Ves_Setup' => 1,
```

changed:

```
'Ves_Setup' => 0,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command to enable disable modules by specific company name.

For example:-

**For enable all below modules in single command**

1. Vendor_Module1
2. Vendor_Module2
3. Vendor_Module3
4. Vendor_Module4
5. Vendor_Module5
6. Vendor_Module6
7. Vendor_Module8
8. Vendor_Module9
9. Vendor_Module10

**Run below command in your Magento setup.**

```
php bin/magento module:enable $(php bin/magento module:status | grep '^Vendor_' | grep -v '^List|^None|^Magento|^$'| xargs)
```

**For Disabled all above modules in single command**

```
php bin/magento module:disable $(php bin/magento module:status | grep '^Vendor_' | grep -v '^List|^None|^Magento|^$'| xargs)
```